# Why does Scala subclass create a copy of fields when inheriting using a primary constructor?

Tags: scala, inheritance

Why does subclass create a copy of field when inheriting using a primary constructor?

For example

```
object Question
{
  class Animal(var name : String) {

    def setName(name : String) {
      this.name = name
    }
  }

  class Dog(name : String) extends Animal(name) {
    this.setName("dog: " + name)

    override def toString: String = this.name // this actually returns "Billy"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val dog = new Dog("Billy")
    println(dog.toString) // output "Billy", why?
    println(dog.name) // output "dog: Billy", why?
  }
}
```

As you can see, `dog.toString()` returns "Billy" instead of "dog: Billy", does it mean `this.name` is different from inherited `name` ? If so, then why does `dog.name` return "dog: Billy" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run your compiler with the `-Xlint` option you should see the following.

> warning: private[this] value name in class Dog shadows mutable name
>   inherited from class Animal.  Changes to name will not be visible
>   within class Dog - you may want to give them distinct names.

If you rename the `name` argument to the `Dog` class, the warning goes away and the output is more consistent and perhaps closer to what's expected.

Comment: Ok. So primary constructor will create fields for whatever parameters passed in, isn't that a waste of resource if all I want is passing them to super class's constructor?

Comment: I know that fact for a long time. And never stop wondering why there is no way to specify constructor argument without creating `private[this]` field behind the scene

Comment: "isn't that a waste of resource if all I want is passing them to super class's constructor" But you don't: you use it in `toString`. That's why the compiler has to store it in a field. If you don't use the argument outside the constructor, no field should be created.

Comment: @ayvango There is: just don't use the constructor argument outside the constructor. What there is not is a way to tell the compiler to make sure you don't use it accidentally (like there is with `@tailRec` or `@switch`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code debug result

[image: your code debug result].

So, what you can see is that there are really actually two instances of variable "name". One is from "Animal", and one from "Dog". Constructors work a little bit different in Scala - what you call constructor arguments are actually local variables that are initialized with constructor arguments.
I can't really provide any elegant solution to this, unfortunately.
Also, I might be wrong. Please correct me if I am.

### Update

[Try this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398344/why-it-is-not-possible-to-override-mutable-variable-in-scala)

Comment: It looks to me those constructor arguments are actually fields, since `this.name` returns "Billy".

Comment: @taffykula, well, they are, actually. If you add `var` to `Dog.name`, you should get an error because of a name clash, see that post down bellow my answer for further explanations. So you should basically deal with how any constructor parameter is going to be a variable because this is how Scala ideology is. You could probably deal with this by renaming `Dog.name` to something else and assigning this value to `Animal.name`. After that just use `Animal.name` only.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can edit the old comment. By saying "a local variable", I mean "a variable in scope of an instance" e.g. "a field", basically.