# What are all the overriding rules between def, val, lazy val, and var in scala?

Tags: scala, oop, overriding

In scala, there are four kinds of member modifier, i.e. `def`, `val`, `lazy val`, `var`. There is a seemingly complicated and inconsistent set of rules regarding overriding, for instance, `def` can be overridden by `val`, while not the other way around. It would be great to see a full list of all these rules.

Comment: The underlying principle is that you can't loosen a superclass's contract in a subclass. `val` can override `def` because it doesn't break any promise `def` made, but `val` promises to return the same value every time, so you can't override with `def` which might return something different each time.

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks, this is indeed one of the major principles. But IMHO, it seems that this cannot explains everything. For instance, Why cannot a concrete `var` be overridden by another `var` while `val` can be overridden by `val`? Why `var` cannot be overridden by `def` since `var` can be seen as a pair of `def`(read and write)? (some discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623074/why-its-impossible-to-override-var-with-def-in-scala)

Comment: re: two `def`s together teaming up together to override one `var`, I think that's covered by the principle I stated — `var` has a certain semantics you can rely on, but those `def`s could be doing anything. re `var` overriding `var`, I don't know about that one. Would it be useful to do so?

Comment: @SethTisue Thank you for your explanation, that make sense to me.

Answer (score 14):

All overridings in scala fall into two categories, the first case is to override an abstract member(in `trait` or `abstract class`) and the other is to override a concrete member:

#### Override concrete members

`def`, `val`, `lazy val`, `var` might all be overridden in subclasses:

1. `def`: can be overridden by all kinds of members(`def`, `val`, `lazy val`, and `var`).
2. `val`: can only be overridden by `val`.
3. `lazy val`: can only be overridden by `lazy val`.
4. `var`: a concrete `var` cannot be overridden.

#### Override abstract members

`lazy val` cannot be abstract, so there are only three rules:

1. `def`: can be overridden by all kinds of members(`def`, `val`, `lazy val`, and `var`).
2. `val`: can be overridden by `val` and `lazy val`.
3. `var`: can be overridden by (1) `var`, or (2) a pair of read and write operations implemented by `def`, `val`, or `lazy val`.

**EDITED:**

As pointed out by @iuriisusuk, please refer to the [related section in spec](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#overriding) for a formal description.

Comment: To make this a perfect answer, you would not only rely on experiments, but also check out if the Scala language spec has to way. You see - experiments can depend on versions and local setups.

Comment: @GhostCat, thanks for your suggestion, the reason why I experiment is exactly that I have not yet found any organized rules in official documents or even blogs. I will edit my answer if I find them. Please also let me know if you have any good resource about this topic :)

Comment: `lazy val` can appear in a trait. Do you mean it can't be abstract?

Comment: @LifuHuang here is a link that formally describes most of the thing you have mentioned, like overriding and modifiers http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html. The only minus is that it's a lot =)

Comment: @iuriisusuk, thanks. I have attach the link in my answer for reference. And yes, I think it might be too formal and scattered for gaining an insight from.

Comment: Maybe you could inline my answer (what the spec says). I think it's simpler than a grid. Maybe explain the rules better?

Comment: @som-snytt Thank you for your fantastic answer. Since your answer has already been a complete and excellent answer in its own right, why not just leave both answers there. Your answer gives the consistent principles behind the rules, and my "grid" gives supporting experiment results(stays on the surface, but might be useful). And let the readers take whatever they need :)

Answer (score 2):

The two rules from [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variable-declarations-and-definitions) are:

- "A stable member can only be overridden by a stable member."
- lazy val must be overridden by lazy val.

The restriction, that vars can't override vars, is because they didn't want to emit two fields for the two vars. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398344/why-it-is-not-possible-to-override-mutable-variable-in-scala).